# How to detect if finger already over the button on start new Activity

Tags: android, events, android-layout, touch

The scenario is that for instance user longclick on **Activity A**.
**Activity A** on lonkclick starts **Activity B** while user does not lift his finger.
**Activity B** should detect that user is still touching screen.

I tried to achive it by...

in **Activity A**

```
ButtonA.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class), REQUEST_1);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

in **Activity B**...

```
ButtonB.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        int oldEvent = -1;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (oldEvent != event.getAction()) {
                oldEvent = event.getAction();
                Toast.makeText(ActivityB.this, event.getAction() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

ButtonA and ButtonB are, for instance, on the same position on screen. Absolutely/

But **ButtonB** took **no events** when **ActivityB** is started. Neither ACTION_DOWN, nor ACTION_UP, no others. Generally I want to receive ACTION_UP on **ButtonB** :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is solved using FragmentActivity.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail the solution to the problem? Because just extending FragmentActivity does not solve any problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the finger is on the screen already when you start your activity you will not get ACTION_DOWN. Also you will not get ACTION_UP, because there was no ACTION_DOWN yet. Maybe you got your own reasoning to do this that way, but in general user should be able to cancel the action, therefore buttons should react on click (DOWN and then UP on the same object). If action takes place on DOWN, then there's no way for user co cancel it (i.e. by moving finger outside the object and lifting it).

Comment: If I understand OP correctly, the buttons are in separate Activities

Comment: Generally it does not matter in those buttons. I want to receive event or elsewhat in ActivityB when the user will lift the finger.

Comment: but again - to have ACTION_UP you need ACTION_DOWN first.

Comment: Are you sure by 100% that there is no way to detect on activityB if the user lift the finger if it is (the finger) already on screen the moment activityB is started?